# Can I reconfigure robot speed when navigation?

Tags: navigation, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, now I have a task about navigation.
I want my robot to have different speeds in different environments.
Just like this:

- At corridor : 0.5m/s
- At parlor : 0.25m/s
- etc...

Now my question is how to reconfigure my robot's speed when navigation?
This is my design step:

- First, Navigate to a place.
- When it finished, reconfigure robot speed.
- Then navigate to next place.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible?

Or there are other way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281770/can-i-reconfigure-robot-speed-when-navigation?/) by [TifferPelode](https://answers.ros.org/users/27959/tifferpelode/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2018-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use `dyanmic_reconfigure` to change (Maximum) velocities on the fly, if it is implemented in the respective local planner.

E.g.

- `base_local_planner` has `max_vel_x` and `min_vel_x` dynamically configureable.
- `dwa_local_planner` seems to have the same.

For other local planners, you'd have to check.

---

**EDIT**

There is a [python Client](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/UsingTheDynamicReconfigurePythonClient).
And it seems that a [C++ Client has been merged](https://github.com/ros/dynamic_reconfigure/pull/78/files) as well, though there is no documentation.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TifferPelode](https://answers.ros.org/users/27959/tifferpelode/) on 2018-02-05**:
It actually work! thx.

And now I want to know how to adjustment the value automatic rather than in GUI ?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-02-06**:
great to hear.  See edit above.

**Comment by [TifferPelode](https://answers.ros.org/users/27959/tifferpelode/) on 2018-02-07**:
Thank you for your patience to answer my question!
;)

**Comment by [violator](https://answers.ros.org/users/56046/violator/) on 2020-12-31**:
@TifferPelode Can you please mention how you adjust the values programmatically rather than using the GUI?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-01-04**:
@violator this is what the clients above are for. You change the values programmatically using the links in the edit I provided above. Does this answer your question?

**Comment by [violator](https://answers.ros.org/users/56046/violator/) on 2021-01-04**:
@mgruhler Yes. It does. And It works.